# AWS System Manager JSON powershell delete files after X days runpowershellscript

Tags: json, powershell, amazon-web-services, system, aws-ssm

The issue, I need to go to multiple servers via a System Manager Document.  To do so, I need to create a json calling the aws runpowershellscript that will call use a powershell script to look for and delete files after X days.  I am having a tough time finding anything like I need except for the various generic walkthroughs. The below doesn't validate as a good json and I assume the powershell script isn't complete but I don't know what is missing.  What have is:

```
{
"schemaVersion": "1.2",
"description": "List information about the .NET Framework version. We recommend exporting results to an Amazon S3 bucket. Output can exceed the maximum.",
"runtimeConfig": {
    "aws:runPowerShellScript": {
        "properties": [
            {
                "id": "0.aws:runPowerShellScript",
                "runCommand": [                     
                  "  Get-ChildItem –Path 'c:\inetpub\* -Recurse -Filter *.log' | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))} | Remove-Item"                     
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So I was able to get this to run but modified but it's ignoring the older than flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using works.  Saw the last person's advice too late:

```
    {
"schemaVersion": "1.2",
"description": "List information about the .NET Framework version. We recommend exporting results to an Amazon S3 bucket. Output can exceed the maximum.",
"runtimeConfig": {
    "aws:runPowerShellScript": {
        "properties": [
            {
                "id": "0.aws:runPowerShellScript",
                "runCommand": [
                  "$Now = Get-Date",
                  "$Days = '14'",
                  "$TargetFolder = 'C:\\inetpub\\*'",
                  "$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)",
                  "$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include *.log*, *.txt* -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite}",
                  "foreach ($File in $Files)", 
                  "    {",
                  "    if ($File -ne $NULL)",
                  "        {",
                  "        write-host 'Deleting File $File' -ForegroundColor 'White'",
                  "        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null",
                  "        }",
                  "    else",
                  "        {",
                  "        Write-Host 'No more files to delete!' -foregroundcolor 'Green'",
                  "        }",
                  "    }"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?  The -Path had a different character and the \s were not escaped.

```html
{
 "schemaVersion": "1.2",
 "description": "List information about the .NET Framework version. We recommend exporting results to an Amazon S3 bucket. Output can exceed the maximum.",
 "runtimeConfig": {
  "aws:runPowerShellScript": {
   "properties": [{
    "id": "0.aws:runPowerShellScript",
    "runCommand": [
     "Get-ChildItem -Path \"c:\\inetpub\\*\" -Recurse -Filter *.log | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))} | Remove-Item"
    ]
   }]
  }
 }
}
```

So, I find with SSMs it's easier to write up a separate cmdlet that will just take a .ps1 file, escape it and json-ify, and slap that into the SSM JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make note of this.  I got frustrated and talked directly to AWS and got an answer for a bit of a different way to do this.